# Spring Cloud Stream in Resource Constrained Environment

Tags: embedded, microservices, iot, spring-cloud-stream

Is Spring Cloud Stream suitable for development of microservices in highly resource-constrained environments (e.g. 2 GB RAM and 2 GB disk)? Is there a binder that is particularly well suited for such environments (assuming modest throughput requirements)?

Comment: "in highly resource-constrained environments (e.g. 2 GB RAM and 2 GB disk)" I don't think you share the same definition of highly resource-constrained as the majority of embedded systems development :) What you describe is a PC computer which is slightly constrained by today's standards.

Comment: @Lundin Good point ;-) I should have been more clear in indicating that I am referring to environments that are more resource constrained than those that would generally run Java applications. Trust me, I have developed enough software on little 8 bit MCUs (e.g. with 128B RAM and 2K FLASH, 33 khz clock, etc) to know what a 'real' constrained environment is :-)

Answer (score 1):

With regard to RAM, 2GB is way more than enough. As far as disk, that is really up to the application, size of messages etc., as Spring Cloud Stream does not itself have any local storage features (other than the size of application and configuration files themselves).